# How to return data from two table into model?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern

I have two tables (model):

Produce table:

```
Id
Name
Price
```

Color table:

```
Id
ProduceId
Color
```

I want to show colors, on the produces. for example:

```
1. green-------- Produce1
2. Red ----------Produce1
3. green --------Produce2
```

my code in repository:

```
public IEnumerable<ColorsVM> GetColors()
        {
            var _query = _context.Colors_tbl.Include(c => c.Produces_tbl).Include(d => d.produceId).AsQueryable();
            return _query;
        }
```

my model: ColorsVM:

```
 public class ColorsVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int produceId { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public Produces Produces { get; set; }
    }
```

but not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should map the foreign key of your `produce` table to be able to load it using `include`.

You can do it either by `Fluent API` or [Data Annotations](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/column-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx). The example below is using **Data Annotations**. Please see the following [link](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-entity-mappings-using-fluent-api.aspx) for more instructions.

```
public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int produceId { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("produceId ")]
    public Produce Produce { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<a.Web.Data.db.Colors>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<a.Web.Models.ViewModels.ColorsVM>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The mapping should be made in your `model` class not in your `view model` class. Your `Color` class (table) should have a property of `Produce` and you may than you can map your `foreign key`.